# Ejabberd Error: {undef, [{ejabberd_auth_storage,start,["localhost"]},

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

When I start Ejabberd by `sudo ejabberdctl live` on ubuntu, it gives some errors:

```
=PROGRESS REPORT==== 9-Jan-2013::15:32:16 ===
          supervisor: {local,ejabberd_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.205.0>},
                       {name,ejabberd_listener},
                       {mfargs,{ejabberd_listener,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,infinity},
                       {child_type,supervisor}]

=INFO REPORT==== 9-Jan-2013::15:32:16 ===
I(<0.40.0>:ejabberd_rdbms:37) : ejabberd has not been compiled with relational database support. Skipping database startup.
*************************** "localhost"
=CRASH REPORT==== 9-Jan-2013::15:32:16 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: application_master:init/4
    pid: <0.39.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {bad_return,
                        {{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                         {'EXIT',
                             {undef,
                                 [{ejabberd_auth_storage,start,["localhost"]},
                                  {lists,foreach,2},
                                  {ejabberd_app,start,2},
                                  {application_master,start_it_old,4}]}}}}
      in function  application_master:init/4
    ancestors: [<0.38.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.38.0>,<0.40.0>,<0.6.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 987
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 141
  neighbours:

=INFO REPORT==== 9-Jan-2013::15:32:16 ===
    application: ejabberd
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {undef,
                         [{ejabberd_auth_storage,start,["localhost"]},
                          {lists,foreach,2},
                          {ejabberd_app,start,2},
                          {application_master,start_it_old,4}]}}}}
    type: temporary
```

Who can tell me the reason, thanks!

Comment: Which detailed version of ejabberd is used? I have downloaded the current version from [github master
](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/tree/master) and doesn't find this file.

Comment: V2.1.11, I also can not find ejabberd_auth_storage.

Comment: I think you could download one stable version, and install it. Maybe it is ubuntu's package management's problem.

Comment: The `undef` error means an undefined function, either the module does not exist/cannot be loaded, or that the function is not exported. In this case the function `ejabberd_auth_storage:start/1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your ejabberd was compiled without `--enable-odbc` key.

Answer (score 0):

The branch master you are using is not finished. Use default branch which is 2.1.x.

Comment: Hi , I have checkout tag 2.1.11, I think the problem is 32bit/64bit problem, but I do know how to compile 32 bit on 64 bit system

Comment: Why do you want to compile in 32bits on a 64bits system ?

Comment: It seems like ejabberd has a 32 bit port